# Display yammer profile picture

Tags: yammer

I am trying to build a web app with yammer integration for login, posting stories, etc. Is is possible to display the yammer profile picture of the user in my web app using yammer API? I have there yammer user id, email, etc.

Answer (score 1):

yes, It can be accessed via Users/Userid. Below is a sample url which will fetch the user's profile feed.

E.g. https://www.yammer.com/api/v1/users/1523361959

In the feed look for `mugshot-url` and you should be good to go. [image]